# Warning when using <?php include 'thefile.php'; ?>

Tags: php

Would need some more help with the

Did ask a question how to import some code with php, in this case it's a sidebar that will be used on some of the pages on a website, It's wordpress and it can execute php from post / page's and have also tested directly in the main code

When i did ask the question the best and most easy thing would be to create a file and use include

Did create thefile.php and did put it in the theme dir where all other .php file's used is, In the file i did just put some basic html like

```
<div id=the-id"> 
      <p> a test text </p>
</div>
```

Then i did put the include code writen as below in my template

```
<?php include 'thefile.php'; ?>
```

Doing this i see my text "a test text" but also get several warning's

```
 Warning: include(/wp-content/themes/thetheme/thefile.php) [function.include]:       failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 22
```

And also this

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening ‘/wp-content/themes/thetheme/thefile.php’ for inclusion (include_path=’.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpsyndicator:/home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-external-links/includes/phpQuery/:/home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-external-links/includes/phpQuery/plugins/’) in /home/cplac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 22
```

Someone that can help me out whit this ? Have tested both in pages but also in the theme files and so on !

Answer (score 6):

The Wordpress method to include php files is to use this function:

```
<?php get_template_part('myfile'); ?>
```

which will include the file myfile.php that is in the same template directory.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part for other parameters.

Comment: Given that the OP (@Mathias) is using WordPress as a framework, _this_ would actually be the best method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `/home/cplac/public_html/` to your include path.

Comment: Thx, that did solve it :D

Comment: @MathiasÅsberg, You should mark this answer as the accepted answer, if this solved your problem.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

include is like

```
include = 'thefile.php';
```

on another note you need to also specify the correct path to the file from the root level or adjacent level of which the file resides.

Say I put a file in my "images" folder on my server for sake of example. And the path to the file would be /images/thefile.php

so with that the include would look like

```
include = '/images/thefile.php';
```

**edit** on a side note, working with WP can sometimes be a pain.. but generally WP is PHP so whatever works in PHP will work with WP overall.

for you based on the error it may be something like..

```
include = '/wp-content/themes/thetheme/thefile.php';
```

But you would need to from your ftp or equivalent navigate to that file path and upload the file into there.

Comment: 1) The include syntax is fine without parenthesies. 2) What is "/images" relative to?

Comment: You are correct.. Im just very used to writing in a different syntax due to the MVC's I use as of late. And images was sake of example.. nothing more

Comment: As far as I know, this is totally wrong! This triggers a syntax error in PHP. `include` is a keyword, you cannot assign anything to it.